# ng-click not working on inner div

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a very simple thing I am trying to do. The ng-click is not working. Any ideas why? Is there a problem with divs that are embedded in another div or am I just too sleepy? That item affected is not included in the code below, but no event is ever registered with the click.

```
<div ng-switch-when="3" ng-mouseenter="showIcons=true" ng-mouseleave="showIcons=false">
    <div ng-if="editPerm" ng-show="showIcons" class="icon_holder" style="width: {{obj.mainwidth}}px;">
    <div class="deletebutton"></div>
    <div ng-click="equationShow=!equationShow" class="equationspecs"></div>
</div>
<div class="equationBlock">
    <div class="eqshow" id="{{obj.itemid}}" ng-show="!obj.showEdit" ng-dblclick="obj.showEdit=!obj.showEdit">
    <span mathjax-bind="obj.data.Format_left"></span>=
    <span mathjax-bind="obj.data.Format_showequation"></span>=
    <span mathjax-bind="obj.data.Format_showsolution"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were able to click on a div with no content in it (sometimes a hard thing to do!), it would simply invert the value of equationShow on the scope.

But that would produce no visible difference. From what I can see in your example, the value of equationShow isn't being used in any way.

Based on your comment, you've probably got a problem with variable scoping.

If, for instance, you did something like this, it'd be more likely to work:

```html
<div ng-init="myVariable = false">
  <div ng-if="!myVariable">
    <div ng-click="$parent.myVariable = !$parent.myVariable">Show the other div</div>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="myVariable">
     Showing this div
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that variable simply controls the display of another div on a separate part of the document. It flips from true to false, etc. However, no event is registered regardless of the action.

Comment: Yes. as it turns out, I needed three parents to do the job. I tried one and two and then gave up. When I saw your answer I tried three.